# How to add data volume to ElasticSearch docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have created a `docker-compose.yml` for **Elasticsearch** and **Kibana** as shown below. The `docker-compose.yml` is working fine but with no index and data. I remember in one of my database specific `docker-compose.yml` I adds data like as shown below and within the **docker/db** folder I places my dq sql scripts

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: some_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Now the question similarly to be above way how do I specify ES index and data volume, what should be the ES file extension

To be more specific I want the below ES index and data to be there when the elasticsearch is started

```
PUT test

POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "name" : "A" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "name" : "B" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "name" : "C" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "name" : "D" }
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  # Elasticsearch Docker Images: https://www.docker.elastic.co/
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: please don't use 7.4, it's EOL and 7.15 was just released! you've got a volume defined there that should work, is it not?

Comment: @MarkWalkom I want to add data (ES index and data) to `elasticsearch-data` how to do that

Comment: that looks valid, from what I know. does it not work?

Comment: @MarkWalkom no my question is should I create any file with the name `elasticsearch-data` and place all the ES queries for creating index and inserting data. For postgres docker-compose file which I have shown I have created a folder docker/db within which I places my dq sql scripts

Comment: oh right, not that's not how that works. that definition means that the Elasticsearch container will store data locally in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` (which is the default), and docker translates that to a directory outside the container called `elasticsearch-data`. that means that all the indexed data you send to the cluster will be stored in that directory

Comment: @MarkWalkom so how do I populate my own ES index and data via docker-compose

Comment: I don't think you need to do that, use the API that is exposed on 9200

Comment: @MarkWalkom you mean via Dockerfile and shell script